# JQuery load(); function doesn't loop with for each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the loop that loads all images from a certain pages from an array. Here's how it works: I have an array which contains URLs. I want to load images from all of these pages to a certain div, but jQuery `load();` function only loads images from one page from the `array` and it's doing it randomly. So every time I get different images but from only one page.

```
var pages = ["artificial-waterfall.htm", "artificial-waterfall01.htm", "artificial-waterfall02.htm", "artificial-waterfall04.htm", "artificial-waterfall05.htm", "artificial-waterfall07.htm", "artificial-waterfall08.htm"];

pages.forEach(function(value, i) {   
   $('.slides').append('<div class="slide"></div>')
   $('.slide').load('/russian/wild-stonenew/' + pages[i] + " .fancybox", function(){
      $('.slide .fancybox').attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery1');
   });
});
```

Comment: it's not random, it just depends on the length of time it takes to load the page as the loads in the each are asynchronous.  If you want to make it synchronous, then you will need to move it out of the each loop and then use the callback function to load the next page after the first page has finished

Comment: also, won't each iteration create a new div of class slide and load the same html into each div with that class on each iteration? perhaps better to use id ="slide".i
to have a unique reference to each new div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per my comment - the load is not random, it just depends on the length of time it takes to load the page as the loads in the each are asynchronous. If you want to make it synchronous, then you will need to move it out of the each loop and then use the callback function to load the next page after the first page has finished.

Instead of doing the load in the each loop, you could do something like this:

```js
var pages = ["artificial-waterfall.htm", "artificial-waterfall01.htm", "artificial-waterfall02.htm", "artificial-waterfall04.htm", "artificial-waterfall05.htm", "artificial-waterfall07.htm", "artificial-waterfall08.htm"];

var currentPage = 0;                  // global counter 
var $slidesContainer = $('.slides');  // slide container

addSlide();                           // set loop going

function addSlide() {
  $slide = $('<div class="slide"></div>');  // create new slide
  $slidesContainer.append($slide);          // append to container

  $slide.load('/russian/wild-stonenew/' + pages[currentPage] + " .fancybox", function() {  // load images into slide
    $slide.find('.fancybox').attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery1');    // do your fancybox thing
    currentPage++;                                                 // increment page index

    if (currentPage < pages.length) {                              // load next slide if there is one
      addSlide();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Man! You are my savior! I can't thank enough this is just what I needed! Million thanks to you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you face is due to the fact that [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) replaces the content of elements. The documentation says the following:

> **Description:** Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.

To resolve this you can do a few things. The easiest being simply appending the content to the element instead of replacing it. This can be done by using for example [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of `.load()`.

Keep in mind that content will be placed "randomly" based on the load speeds. The slowest data will be appended last, but this may vary on refreshes.

Another option is first creating placeholders where the content for each URL should go. Then use `.load()` to replace the content of the placeholders with the remote data. This will leave the loaded content in the order of the array, since you first reserve a spot for the content and then load data into it.